# Delete a percent of list elements

Tags: c#, image

Let's say I have a list of numbers like

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Now I want to delete 50% of the list so i would have now a list like
1 3 5 7 9

I don't want to remove the first 50% , so not this
6 7 8 9 10

I want to regularly delete from the list.
I'm trying to implement this in C# or JAVA.

I know that sometime is not possible to remove that percent exactly but something close will be ok.

My procent is always an integer, so is from 0 to 100 .

I'm trying to do this with an N percent for a list, how should I start?

Comment: Show some code, describe exactly what doesn't work. StackOverflow is not about *I need code, give me code*. We can help you, we wan't write the entire thing for you.

Comment: it's strange question... var list = new List<int>
            {
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6,
                7,
                8,
                9,
                10
            };

            var clearList = list.Where(x => x%2 == 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
List<int> source = new List<int>() {
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

// Take every other item from the list
List<int> result = source
  .Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0)
  .ToList();
```

General case should be elaborated a little bit:

```
int percent = 50;

List<int> result = source
  .Where((item, index) =>
         (index == 0) || 
         (index * percent / 100) > ((index - 1) * percent / 100))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: @Matthijs: Sorry, but my solution retuns items with 0, 2, 4,... indexes which correspond to 1, 3, 5, ... items

Comment: Ahhh you're right, sorry, I misread! But that still doesn't answer his question correctly.

Comment: I think is working, but I choose the percent that i want to stay not to be deleted haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int halfNumOfList = myList.Count / 2;
    int itemsRemoved = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (itemsRemoved < halfNumOfList)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                myList.Remove(myList[i]);
                itemsRemoved++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will delete only half, is no N here, and you will probably get an exception because you need to go back once when you delete..